# Connecting to Python socket from iOS Safari browser

Tags: python, sockets, mobile-safari

I have a python socket listening on my computer's ip address on a specific port. I am using the standard python socket library with something like the following code:

```
listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind(server_address) # Server address is a tuple (HOST, PORT) with host being 
                                   # something like 123.456.789.00 and port being 4000
listen_socket.listen()
client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
request_data = client_connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(request_data)
```

When I use Chrome on my iPhone to connect to the address, the rest of my code runs fine and processes the incoming request by sending an html page. When I use Safari, it loads for a while until it fails and a says "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server."

Funny enough, if I stay on the page, restart the server, and then reload the page using the refresh button, it connects fine. But trying to access the address through the url address does not work. Refreshing using the refresh button seems to work. Why is Safari having trouble connecting to my Python socket?

Comment: The problem will be later  in your code and may have something to do with the html you send back to the browser. Does the html contain other urls to this server that would hang because you don't allow simultaneous connections? Just a guess!

Comment: *...something like the following code...* The code in your question doesn't do anything and therefore couldn't be anything like code that "sends an html page".

Comment: @tdelaney I had more code but the execution did not pass "request_data = client_connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')" until I cancelled loading the page on my phone, which is why I didn't add the rest. Sorry I should have mentioned

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk refer to my above comment. I could only tag one person at a time

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the backlog count in the listen_socket.listen() call.

I had a similar issue with a python 2 socket server and macOS Safari.  Safari would say it could not connect to the server, but Chrome/Firefox/IE/curl all worked without any errors. I changed this:

```
listen_socket.listen(1)
```

To this:

```
listen_socket.listen(5)
```

Safari then worked without any errors.  I am now using 128 instead of 5, not sure what the default is in Python 3.

When set to 1, in the python server I would see Safari connect, but then socket.recv() would never return.